# How to Edit Facebook Application name?

Tags: android, facebook

I have created one application on Facebook for integration with Android and iOS Application, for some reason i want to edit Application name, i have edited Display name but the application name is displayed old name not edited name. anybody know any other way for change application name ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: sorry, I don't think is possible

Comment: What is the `Application name`? I only see `Display Name` and `Namespace` in app settings.

Comment: Jurik, not displayed application name in Facebook application, i think Display name is application name and i have changed it but not any effect..